# decompressing huge json gzip file causing memory error in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, gzip, zlib

I got the following problem.
I am working with small machine with low memory (1 GB).
my program download a huge gzip file from some url. And I need to decompress it to **dict** I know for sure that the file is in **json** format.
My problem is that after I run the following command I got a **memory error**:

```
data = zlib.decompress(url, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS).decode('utf8')
results_list.append(json.loads(data ))
```

now for small files this works fine, but for large I got the error.
my intuition tells me that I should split the file into chunks, but then because I am expecting a json file i wont be able to restore the chunks back to json (because each part wont be a valid json string).

what I should do?

Thank a lot!

Comment: No need to split it in chucks: use a handle instead of string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you elaborate please handle where?

Comment: some body? I am totally lost...

Comment: Define "huge"..

Comment: Around 200 mb. @MarkAdler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a decompression object using `z=zlib.decompressobj()`, and then do `z.decompress(some_compressed_data, max)`, which will return no more than `max` bytes of uncompressed data. You then call again with `z.decompress(z.unconsumed_tail, max)` until the rest of `some_compressed_data` is consumed, and then feed it more compressed data.

You will need to then be able to process the resulting uncompressed data a chunk at a time.

Comment: Hi thank you so much... can you please explain what would you recommend for the value of max? and how I access the decompressed data, and how can I tell whether there is an unconsumed_tail.